# Failed to pull image "draft:dev"

Tags: jenkins-x

When I generated code with the Quickstart (angular project), I got a project that gets deployed on Aruze in my Kubernetes. I can also access this Angular application from the internet, everything is fine.

For my own application, if Jenkins-x build is run and the application wants to be deployed in the staging environment, I see an error that my container can't be found.

```
Failed to pull image "draft:dev": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for draft, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Under deployment the Images shows "draft:dev", while for the Quickstart application it shows for example mytryout.azurecr.io/company/newui:0.0.5

I can't find the problem, charts seems to be fine. In which direction do I have to look?

Answer (score 0):

`draft:dev` is the default image in the helm chart, but your `Jenkinsfile` should have an override with `--image` for each build like this https://github.com/carlossg/croc-hunter-jenkinsx-serverless/blob/16773d0115f184be4ad82d34789082a17380e157/Jenkinsfile#L60

Answer (score 0):

usually Jenkins X will update the `charts/myapp/values.yaml` file to set the `image.repository` and `image.tag` values to the fully qualified docker image name and the version as part of the release pipeline then this will be tagged in your git repository.

e.g. see this example of 0.0.1 of a quickstart: https://github.com/jstrachan/nodey89/blob/v0.0.1/charts/nodey89/values.yaml#L5-L7

this is done by the command `jx step next-version --filename package.json --tag`

I guess based on the layout of your project or folder for the chart files this command isn't properly updating your `values.yaml` file.

Maybe try run that command from your source code and see if there is a meaningful error as to why its not updating those values? You probably will see errors in your pipeline log when creating the release too